# Adding a global wrapper to enzyme mounts using jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-query

### Background

So I'm adding react query to a project and am running into a problem with my enzyme tests. For those that have used RQ v3, you know that it requires a `QueryClientProvider` wrapper. This is fine for my app, but a test like this:

```js
...
const mountedComponent = () => {
    return mount(<Component {...props} />);
};
```

will now fail unless I add a wrapper like this:

```js
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
const queryClient = new QueryClient();
...
const mountedComponent = () => {
    return mount(<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}><Component {...props} /></QueryClientProvider>);
};
```

### Question

Is it possible to add a global wrapper for the jest side, maybe in `setupTests` so I can add `QueryClientProvider` there once instead of on every test that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

best answer so far from discord:

a wrapper around mount rather than a wrapper around your component might be possible:

```js
const mountWithQueryClient = (component) => mount(<QueryClientProvider client={new QueryClient()}>{component}</QueryClientProvider>)
```

you could then import that instead of mount , but it would still mean touching all your tests :/